# Style binding and ngStyle none seem to work to set background image inside a DIV in Angular5

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I was using Angular material cards but somehow was unable to change the spacing as I wanted inspite of trying many css styles So I thought of creating by own cards.
While doing that I have to set an image as a background inside a div.

I have tried many ways,

```
<div *ngIf="imgSrc" [style.background-image]="imgSrc" [style.background-size]="cover"></div>
```

this style doesn't show an error but I don't seem to see any image inside my div

and even using ngStyle I am getting error when trying,

```
<div *ngIf="imgSrc" [ngStyle]="{
    'background-image': 'url(\'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg\')'
  }"></div>

Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 43 in expression [{
    'background-image': 'url(\'https:] at column 44 in [{
    'background-image': 'url(\'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg\')'
  }] in ng:///AppModule/HomeCardComponent.html@37:26
```

Though I don't want to set using url but using imgSrc which is the url that I am passing from the component.

And how do I set the imgSrc using ngStyle because it throws an error when using interpolation as well?

[image: image has to come on the right half of the card]

My html code is as follows:

```
<div class="card shadow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 card-body">
      <div class="card-domain">{{ domain }}</div>
      <div class="card-title">{{ title }}</div>
      <div class="card-date">{{ date }}</div>
      <div class="card-content">{{ content }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div *ngIf="imgSrc" [style.background-image]="imgSrc" [style.background-size]="cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

home-card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-card',
  templateUrl: './home-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-card.component.css']
})
export class HomeCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() domain: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() date: string;
  @Input() content: string;
  @Input() imgSrc: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

home-card.component.css

```
.card{
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

home.component.ts

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Latest Post</h3>
        </div>
        <app-home-card domain="XYZ" title="It should work!" date="Nov 12" content="Let's just assume it's working." imgSrc="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"></app-home-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Most Popular Post</h3>
        </div>
        <app-home-card domain="ABC" title="Why is it not working?" date="Nov 11" content="Or make it work somehow." imgSrc="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"></app-home-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try do it as follow: `[style.background-image]="'url(' + imgSrc + ')'"`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** check your urls 
**2.** you have do it as follow:`'url(' + imgSrc + ')'`

```
<div class="card shadow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 card-body">
      <div class="card-domain">{{ domain }}</div>
      <div class="card-title">{{ title }}</div>
      <div class="card-date">{{ date }}</div>
      <div class="card-content">{{ content }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div *ngIf="imgSrc" [style.background-image]="'url(' + imgSrc + ')'" [style.background-size]="cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: do you check your url

Comment: do it with expression `[style.background-image]="'url(' + {{imgSrc }}+ ')'"`

Comment: Got an error : `Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 9 in ['url(' + {{imgSrc }}+ ')']`

Comment: no error but image is still not showing up. 
this is the url (https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170933/discussion-between---and-karan-nagpal).